# How to move an image from left to right in android

Tags: android, animation

I'd like to translate an image from left to right on emulator using android animation. I'm new to android animation. How could I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 60):

```
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Animation");

    moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0, 0);
    moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1000);
    moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);

    button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    button.setText("PressMe");
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
        }

    });

    ll.addView(tv);
    ll.addView(button);
    setContentView(ll);
```

is one way of doing it.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for ur reply.I tried with ur above example.But it displays only the word "Animation" without any move.

Comment: @Sudhakar.  Sorry missed off the `Animation.setDuration(1000)` and `Animation.setFillAfter(true)`.

Comment: @Pete.  Apologies.  I will remove the link from the answer.  Thanks for the heads up ;).

Comment: @techiServices how to animate two texts from middle to opposite direction ?

Comment: @juned. create two animations eg centerLeft and centerRight with the correct values for the screen size.  so center ie start would be screenwidth/2.  left edge is 0, right edge is screenwidth.  If that is not clear can you post a new question?

Comment: @techiServices Thanks for response here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191948/how-to-animate-two-image-view-from-center-to-opposite-to-each-other

Answer (score 35):

Move an image from left to right and right to left by using Android TranslateAnimation

[image]

```
ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f);          //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
    animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration 
    animation.setRepeatCount(5);  // animation repeat count
    animation.setRepeatMode(2);   // repeat animation (left to right, right to left )
    //animation.setFillAfter(true);      

    img_animation.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation
```

[you can find more details from here](http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2013/06/how-to-move-an-image-from-left-to-right-and-right-to-left-in-android.html)

Comment: This Is moving an image outside the boundary/edge of the screen. It should bounce back to the edge I think

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party but worth answering here,

**case 1:**

if your view is at the left side of the screen and you want to **move from left edge to right edge** then use this:

```
imageView.animate()
            .translationX(((rootLayout.width - (imageView.width))).toFloat())
            .setInterpolator(AccelerateInterpolator()).duration = 1500
```

**case 2:**
If your view is at the center of the screen and you want to **move from center to right edge** then use this:

```
imageView.animate()
            .translationX(((rootLayout.width - (imageView.width)) / 2).toFloat())
            .setInterpolator(AccelerateInterpolator()).duration = 1500
```

**NOTE:**
`rootLayout` is root view of your XML

Answer (score -2):

Add this code R.anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="800" />
</set>
```