# Creating a background image that moves from right to left in a live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have a background image that I would like to simply scroll (while looping) right to left. What is the best way to go about doing this? Will I need to use an external library? Are there certain methods built into android already to accomplish this? Is all this accomplished in the `doDraw()` method?

Eventually I would like the canvas to also draw a stationary Bitmap ontop of that. I think that will be easy if I just use the canvas.drawBitmap() function.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689918/move-image-from-left-to-right-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Easy example including X offset 
http://android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/256-live-wallpaper-example
and canvas