# Animate ImageView across wide image

Tags: java, android, animation, android-imageview

I have very wide image, and I want an infinite animation that moves the ImageView across that image. For example this is my start point:
[image]

And I want to animate the ImageView to this point of view:
[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

And so on until my ImageView will reach the end of the actual image, and then it will return to the start point.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689918/move-image-from-left-to-right-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
TranslateAnimation LefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, width,0, 0);
LefttoRight.setDuration(700);
LefttoRight.setFillAfter(false);
image.startAnimation(LefttoRight);
```

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. It moves all the ImageView and not the image inside it.